# How can I create a custom shortcut to a website on my Desktop?

Tags: chromium, shortcuts

I'm trying to convert this MS Windows shortcut to Ubuntu/GNOME.

How do I create a Chromium incognito shortcut (with website) on the desktop?

This example is for the Yandex Browser (but I will be using Chromium)

`C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Yandex\YandexBrowser\Application\browser.exe 
-incognito --app=http://www.websitehere.com`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example for creating a shortcut to askubuntu.com

Create the following text file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shortcut to askubuntu.com
GenericName=askubuntu
Comment=ask the community for help
Exec=chromium-browser --incognito askubuntu.com
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/myusername/path/to/my/icon
StartupNotify=true
```

and save it to `~/.local/share/applications/` as `askubuntu.desktop`

the `~/.local` folder is in your home directory. Unhide it by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> in your file browser.

Right click the file and choose **Properties** and then go into the **Permissions** tab and select *allow executing as program*

Now you should be able to double click the file and drag and drop it wherever you want it to be.

Note: if you don't need a icon for your shortcut you can just delete the

```
icon=...
```

line

if you want one, you gotta download one...

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I just saved it to the Desktop (I'll do the the other steps if I need to move it). P.S. For those reading this, if you need another website(s) just add a space and add the other domain. Also, in my slow computer adding the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) "https://www.website.com" instead of "website.com" loads faster!